# Why Golang object property of byte array will be wiped when assigned to another variable

Tags: go

We need to wipe out some variables after use. But it seems really weird when it's assigned with a `[]byte` field in a struct.

Why this assignment of `[]byte` is not a copy but a pointer?

What should I do to keep the value in struct `a.bs`, but wipe out the `b` as local variable?
http://play.golang.org/p/MT_wAHj2OM

```
package main

import "fmt"

type so struct {
    bs []byte
}

func zeroes(n int) []byte {
    return make([]byte, n)
}

func wipeBytes(b []byte) {
    copy(b, zeroes(len(b)))
}


func main() {
    a := so{bs: []byte{0x01, 0x02}}
    b := a.bs
    wipeBytes(b)
    fmt.Println(b)    //b == []byte{}
    fmt.Println(a.bs) //a.bs == []byte{}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slices are inherently reference-y things. Assigning one doesn't copy its contents. You can think of a slice value as being a "slice head" structure, which contains a pointer to the slice's underlying array, and the offset and length of the slice within the array. It's this structure that's copied when you copy the slice, not any of the values in the array.

You can do

```
b := make([]byte, len(a.bs)))
copy(b, a.bs)
```

to make `b` a new slice and copy `a.bs`'s contents into it. Then nothing you do to one will have any effect on the other.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring/creating the 'array' (`[]byte{0x01, 0x02}`), you're not specifying a length (`[2]byte{0x01, 0x02}`), which means that it's a slice instead of an array. And slices objects internally contains a pointer to it's content.

Answer (score 0):

```
func ObjectAssign(target interface{}, object interface{}) {
    // object atributes values in target atributes values
    // using pattern matching (https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName)
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590190/how-to-use-the-spread-operator-in-golang
    t := reflect.ValueOf(target).Elem()
    o := reflect.ValueOf(object).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < o.NumField(); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < t.NumField(); j++ {
            if t.Field(j).Name() == o.Field(i).Name() {
                t.Field(j).Set(o.Field(i))
            }
        }
    }
}
```