# Better way to test for a value in a list than to stack try's and except's

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, try-except

My code is implementing a Caesar Cipher, and this function is supposed to convert the inputted string, into an encrypted string.

To do this, I have to search for the character in 2 lists, a list of lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and then if it is not a letter, just add the character to the encrypted string.

I decided to use two layers of try's and except's to do this. Is there a better way I could do it, maybe with if/else?

```
import string
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

alphaLower = string.ascii_lowercase
alphaUpper = string.ascii_uppercase
alphaShiftL = alphaLower
alphaShiftU = alphaUpper

def shiftList(amount):
    global alphaShiftL
    global alphaShiftU
    alphaShiftL = alphaLower[amount:] + alphaShiftL[:amount]
    alphaShiftU = alphaUpper[amount:] + alphaShiftU[:amount]

def encrypt(unencrypted):
    encrypted = ''
    for char in unencrypted:
        #HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        try: 
            alphaLower.index(char)
            encrypted += alphaShiftL[alphaLower.index(char)]
        except ValueError:
            try:
                encrypted += alphaShiftU[alphaUpper.index(char)]
            except ValueError:
                encrypted += char

    return encrypted
```

Comment: Use `find` instead of `index` and avoid exceptions altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more efficient ways to implement this -- But working with what you've got, the first thing I might recommend is to concatenate the lists so that you only need 1 try/except:

```
alpha = alphaLower + alphaUpper
alphaShift = alphaShiftL + alphaShiftU
for char in unencrypted:
try: 
    encrypted += alphaShift[alpha.index(char)]
except ValueError:
    encrypted += char
```

Now we've only got a single try/except which is nice.

---

We can do better -- much better -- if we continue working with only a single object that contains the *mapping*.  In this case, what you really want to do is to map a character in alpha to a different character in alphaShift.  We can do this trivially with python dict:

```
mapping = dict(zip(alpha, alphaShift))
for char in unencrypted:
    encrypted += mapping.get(char, char)
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
mapping = dict(zip(alpha, alphaShift))
encrypted = ''.join(mapping.get(char, char) for char in unencrypted)
```

To "decrypt", you just need the inverse mapping:

```
inverse_mapping = dict(zip(alphaShift, alpha))
unencrypted = ''.join(inverse_mapping.get(char, char) for char in encrypted)
```

Comment: But using one list will introduce some complication in `shiftList`. Although there is a better way to implement that too, but it will be entirely different from what OP has got.

Comment: As an extension to gill's comment; if the letter is `z` and the shift is `4`, your solution would come up with `D`.

Comment: @gill -- I don't think that really complicates it.  Maybe it's not really a true Caesar cypher anymore -- It's 2 cyphers stuck together I guess -- But it still works just the same.  The important thing is that OP is using multiple lists to map from one character to another.  As long as that mapping is well defined and used consistently (and it is), it doesn't matter if it is stored in one list or two. . .

Comment: @JackyXie -- That's a generator expression.  If you haven't learned about them yet (or their sister constructs `list-comprehensions`), they're really cool and worth looking up.  For the time being, you can consider it to be equivalent to the loop above.

Comment: It seems to me that OP wants encryption to preserve case. If so, `shiftList` needs to be modified (in a more complicate direction) to work with your solution, and that's all I was saying. OP might tell us that he is OK with altering case, but I wouldn't have guessed that from the question.

Comment: @gill I changed shiftList to alphaShift = ALPHA[amount:26] + ALPHA[0:amount] + ALPHA[26+amount:] + ALPHA[26:26+amount] Now I have to get that under 79 characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
if char.islower():
    encrypted += alphaShiftL[alphaLower.index(char)]
elif char.isupper():
    encrypted += alphaShiftU[alphaUpper.index(char)]
else:
    encrypted += char
```

See documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need to know if something is present in a list.  You can test for collection inclusion with this:

```
if search in collection:
    ix = collection.index(search)
else:
    //handle no
```

Did I understand you correctly?

Edit: mgilson's solution because you need the index of the element.

```
ix = collection.find(search)
if ix != -1:
    //handle yes
else:
    //handle no
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is an academic exercise, I don't see why you're organizing your code this way.  If you feel passionately about keeping the information in arrays, then you can just concatenate them together so you can get by with one lookup.

```
alphaLower = string.ascii_lowercase
alphaUpper = string.ascii_uppercase
alpha = alphaLower + alphaUpper
alphaShift = alpha

def shiftList(amount):
    global alphaShiftL
    global alphaShiftU
    alphaShiftL = alphaLower[amount:] + alphaShiftL[:amount]
    alphaShiftU = alphaUpper[amount:] + alphaShiftU[:amount]
    alphaShift = alphaShiftL + alphaShiftU
```

Now you can do your lookups directly:

```
def encrypt(unencrypted):
    encrypted = ''
    for char in unencrypted:
        idx = alpha.find(char)
        encrypted += alphaShift[idx] if idx >= 0 else char
    return encrypted
```

However, it would be far better to just use a dictionary:

```
lc = string.ascii_lowercase
uc = string.ascii_uppercase

cipher = dict(zip(lc+uc, lc[13:]+lc[:13]+uc[13:]+uc[:13]))

def encrypt(input):
    return ''.join(cipher.get(c,c) for c in input)
```